# Spark rdd split doesn't return last column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, split, rdd

I have the following data:

```
17|ABC|3|89|89|0|0|2|
17|DFD|3|89|89|0|0|2|
17|RFG|3|89|89|0|0|2|
17|TRF|3|89|89|0|0|2|
```

When I use the following code, I just get 8 elements instead of 9 since the last one doesn't contain any value. I can't use Dataframes as my csv is not fixed, every line can have a different number of elements. How can I get last column value even if its Null/None?

My current code:

```
data_rdd.filter(x => x contains '|').map{line => line.split('|')}.foreach(elem => {
      println("size of element ->" + elem.size)
      elem.foreach{elem =>
        println(elem)

      }
})
```

Comment: `my csv is not fixed, it changes every line.` do you get sperator with empty value? or whole column is missing.

Comment: no separator, whole column is missing but shouldn't it return null value or something?

Comment: Got your point. Can you give more information on why do you need the last value as null? Why not skip based on the length of the array?

Comment: @VinayKV I can't since every line has a different length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your string as below:

```
scala> "17|ABC|3|89|89|0|0|2|".split("\\|", -1)
res24: Array[String] = Array(17, ABC, 3, 89, 89, 0, 0, 2, "")
```

updated code:

```
data_rdd.filter(x => x contains '|').map{line => line.split("\\|", -1)}.foreach(elem => {
      println("size of element ->" + elem.size)
      elem.foreach{elem =>
        println(elem)

      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In both Scala and Java, `split` will not return any trailing empty strings by default. Instead, you can use a slightly different version of `split` with a second argument (overloaded to Scala and seen in the Java docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))).

The method definition is:

> split(String regex, int limit)

The second argument here limits how many time the regex pattern is applied, using a negative number will apply it as many times as possible.

Therefore, change the code to use:

```
.map{line => line.split("\\|", -1)}
```

Note that this `split` function takes a regex and not a normal string or char.